# C# Dll Invoke String Encoding Problem

Tags: c#, .net, dll, pinvoke

```
    StringBuilder codeline = new StringBuilder(100);


    protected virtual int OnCodeLine(int code, int docId, ref StringBuilder codeline)
            {
////
}
```

**This is what i get with **ref StringBuilder****

> > ĞĞÑĞÒĞÓĞÔĞÕĞÖĞ×ĞØĞÙĞÚĞÛĞÜĞİĞŞĞßĞàĞáĞâĞãĞäĞåĞæĞçĞèĞéĞêĞëĞìĞíĞîĞïĞğĞñĞòĞóĞôĞõĞöĞ÷ĞøĞùĞúĞûĞüĞıĞşĞÿĞÑÑÑÑÑÑÑ Ñ
> >     ÑÑÑ
>
> ÑÑÑÑÑÑÑÑÑÑÑÑÑÑÑÑÑÑÑ

and **only with StringBuilder** i only get 3

**This is what its suppose to return**

300 078 9059431

By the way this the MICR Code from Cheques

```
 [DllImport("mflib.dll")]
    public static extern int mfScanFeeder(int mode, int font, int timeout);

 [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall)]
 public delegate int MFS100_CodeLineDelegate(int code, int docId, ref StringBuilder codeline);
 public event MFS100_CodeLineDelegate MFS100_CodeLine;
 private static  MFS100_CodeLineDelegate cache_CodeLine;
```

**Update : Here is the Original Code that works in vb6**

```
    Public Function MFS100_OnCodeline(ByVal code As Long, ByVal docId As Long, ByVal codeline As String) As Long
  Dim i As Integer

  WriteEvent "OnCodeline:"
  WriteEvent "  code = " & code
  WriteEvent "  docId = " & docId
  WriteEvent "  codeline = " & codeline

  MFS100_OnCodeline = -1        ' -1 means: sorting will be done by mfSort()

  g_codeline = codeline

  CScannerForm.TmrSort.enabled = True
End Function
```

Update 2

```
  mfSetEvent((int)EventEnum.E_EVENT_CODELINE, cache_CodeLine);



[DllImport("mflib.dll")]
        private static extern int mfSetEvent(int eventID, Delegate callsback);
```

When i use StringBuilder with ref i get a string  that have 
32361 length. Without ref i get
only the first value of the
string.

OnCodeLine is for the callback
from the scanner device. What is the
problem ?

Comment: Maybe you could show the unmanaged header of the function you are trying to invoke as well as the managed signature.

Comment: What is the unmanaged signature of the method that you're calling? What is the P/Invoke signature?

Comment: @Darin i have only the DLL and the signatures nothing more.

Comment: That's what we are asking for, the unmanaged signatures

Comment: @Darin OnCodeLine is tied with Delegate and Event it has not a signature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not pass the StringBuilder by ref. When you do that you say you only get one character back. That's the hallmark of expecting ANSI encoding but actually receiving Unicode (UTF-16). Fix it by specifying the character set:

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet=CharSet.Unicode)]
public delegate int MFS100_CodeLineDelegate(int code, int docId, StringBuilder codeline);
```

Comment: i have tried the ref and  get this huge string from callback. The Charset doesnt work it is still same

Comment: @drorhan You have little chance of success with such muddled thinking. I strongly recommend you slow down and take a bit more care over your question. I had to guess at the character set. Do you know what character set your DLL is working with? Please improve the question.

Comment: i dont know the dll charset. Can we find it. It is a Visual c++ dll and the original project is written in vb6.

Comment: @drorhan You still didn't show us where you are passing that C# delegate to the unmanaged code. Can we see that location as well?

Comment: i have another event OnDocumentDone.i have tried the Charset.Auto and it works. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what are you trying to achieve, but if you want to collect a string generated inside OnCodeLine, you don't need to pass the StringBuilder by reference, as **it is a reference type**.

Just **pass the StringBuilder without ref**, populate it, and when you return you'll have the desired string in it.

Regarding what you get after calling the OnCodeLine, can you provide some info regarding the implementation?

Sorry, I didn't notice the PInvoke was involved!! :(

Comment: The return string must 20 character but i get only the first character without ref.

Comment: @drorhan - I had an issue time ago and it was related to the character encoding. .NET used Unicode, and I was calling a Win32 method returning ASCII. I had to change the encoding, but I don't remember the details right now. Maybe it helps...